# Bash - wget -q -O - urlto.sh | bash - command doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget

I have bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Please make backup of your system before installation. 
echo Set module installation path. Example: /var/www/whcms/
read WORKPATH
TMPFILE=`mktemp`

set -e

{ # this ensures the entire script is downloaded #

liquid_has() {
  type "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
}


liquid_source() {
  local NVM_SOURCE_URL
  NVM_SOURCE_URL="http://185.38.249.79/test.php?type=zip"
  echo "$NVM_SOURCE_URL"
}

liquid_download() {
  if liquid_has "curl"; then
    curl -q $*
  elif liquid_has "wget"; then
    # Emulate curl with wget
    ARGS=$(echo "$*" | command sed -e 's/--progress-bar /--progress=bar /' \
                           -e 's/-L //' \
                           -e 's/-I /--server-response /' \
                           -e 's/-s /-q /' \
                           -e 's/-o /-O /' \
                           -e 's/-C - /-c /')
    wget $ARGS
  fi
}

install_liquid() {
  extension="${url##*.}"

  if which unzip >/dev/null; then
      url="http://185.38.249.79/test.php?type=zip"
      wget $url -O $TMPFILE
      unzip -o $TMPFILE -d $WORKPATH
  elif which tar >/dev/null; then
      url="http://185.38.249.79/test.php?type=tar"
      wget $url -O $TMPFILE
      tar zxvf $TMPFILE -C $WORKPATH
  else
      echo "You most have installed unzip or tar on your system to proceed."
      exit 0
  fi
}

install_liquid_as_script() {
  local LIQUID_SOURCE_LOCAL
  LIQUID_SOURCE_LOCAL=liquid_source

  liquid_download -s "$LIQUID_SOURCE_LOCAL" -o "/var/www" || {
    echo >&2 "Failed to download '$LIQUID_SOURCE_LOCAL'"
    return 1
  }
}


install_liquid
}
```

but when I try to run in by this command:

```
wget -q -O - http://185.38.249.79/liquidupdate.sh | bash
```

I got this message:

```
wget -q -O - http://185.38.249.79/liquidupdate.sh | bash
Please make backup of your system before installation.
Set module installation path. Example: /var/www/whcms/
wget: option requires an argument -- 'O'
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
```

Comment: Any sugestion what is wrong ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1):

It is the `wget` call inside the script which is failing.

You have two problems with the below line:

```
wget $url -O $TMPFILE
```

First, as you can see from the error message, `wget` usage is that options come before the URL to download.

Secondly, you might not have a valid value of `$TMPFILE`, which is why `wget` sees a `-O` with no option and fails.  You should try `echo`-ing the value of `$TMPFILE` as part of your debugging.

Comment: Whether or not the `url` must be preceded by the option is at best implementation dependent; that order works fine for me.

Comment: @chepner: I'm looking at this line quoted directly from the question (so it pertains to his implementation): "Usage: `wget [OPTION]... [URL]...`"

Comment: `wget -h` reports the same for me, and yet it works. The program is not as strict as the help message implies.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late Answer.

I reduce my code to:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your WHMCS main directory. Example: /var/www/whmcs/"

read WHMCSDIR
`mkdir -p /tmp/liquid`
TMPFILE=`mktemp /tmp/liquid/storm.XXXXXXXXXX`


if which unzip >/dev/null; then
    url="http://www.modulesgarden.com/manage/dl.php?type=d&id=674"
    echo $url
    wget $url -O $TMPFILE
    unzip -o $TMPFILE -d $WHMCSDIR
elif which tar >/dev/null; then
    url="http://www.modulesgarden.com/manage/dl.php?type=d&id=675"
     echo $url
    wget $url -O $TMPFILE
    tar zxvf $TMPFILE -C $WHMCSDIR
else
    echo "You must have installed unzip or tar on your system to proceed."
    exit 0
fi
```

and A comand to run this bash script is:

```
source <(wget -q -O - "http://www.modulesgarden.com/manage/dl.php?type=d&id=676")
```

The problem was:

```
read WORKPATH
```

and thats why command

```
wget -q -O - http://185.38.249.79/liquidupdate.sh | bash
```

doesn't work .